# Architecture error when compiling gfortran test code on macOS Monterey (M1)

Tags: gcc, fortran

I was trying to run a basic piece of test code (named **test.f90**) through fortran on macOS Monterey (M1) version 12.3.
The code is:

```
program test
  integer, dimension(2,2) :: f,g
  integer :: i,j
  do i=1,2
     do j=1,2
       f(i,j)=2*i+j
       g(i,j)=i+3*j
    enddo
  enddo
  !print*,f  !  gives f(x1,y1,z1),f(x2,y1,z1),...,f(x1,y2,z1),f(x2,y2,z1),...
  print*,f
  print*,g
  print*,f*g
  print*,f(:,:)*g(:,:)
  f = reshape( (/1,2,3,4/), (/2,2/) )
  print*,sum(f)
end program
```

The gfortran version is: GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3) 11.2.0.
When I did **gfortran test.f90**, the following error popped up:

```
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd' for architecture arm64
```

Comment: Does GNU Fortran support Apple Silicon?

Comment: It looks like [you’re not alone needing a loader guide for Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71507047/475228) on Monterey.